# Communicate between javascript and python in Jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook

```
javascript = """
<script type="text/Javascript">

   function exec_code(){
       var res = confirm("Hello");
       var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
       console.log("show:" + res);
       var callbacks = {
         iopub : {
         output : res,
    }
    }
   IPython.notebook.kernel.execute(res, callbacks);
   }
   exec_code();
</script>
"""

HTML(javascript)
```

I want to have a confirm popup in javascript, and depending on whether user does "OK" or "Cancel", store the value in variable res. Then I want to expose that to python in the same cell in jupyter notebook. I tried callbacks.iopub.output, but does not seem to work.

I want to do a print(**output**) to display the value in res -- true or false.